# KendoUi Angular2 grid in dialog pagination

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Im trying to use Kendoui Angular2 grid within component in Kendo dialog.
When I try to pagging- click on pagging buttons, It doesnt work and Im "thrown" to home page.
Does anyone know if this should work in some way?

code:

```
<kendo-dialog *ngIf="isHelloOpen ">
    <kendo-dialog-titlebar title="hello" (click)="isHelloOpen = false">
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">hello</h2>
    </kendo-dialog-titlebar>

    <hello-component *ngIf="currentPage == 1></hello-component>

    <kendo-dialog-actions class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="isHelloOpen = false">hello</button>
        </div>
    </kendo-dialog-actions>
</kendo-dialog>
```

the grid is within `<hello-component>`.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work when tested locally. The Dialog will render custom component 'hello-grid':

```
<kendo-dialog title="Action required" *ngIf="opened" (close)="close('cancel')">
      <hello-grid></hello-grid>

      <kendo-dialog-actions>
          <button kendoButton (click)="close('yes')" primary="true">Yes</button>
          <button kendoButton (click)="close('no')">No</button>
      </kendo-dialog-actions>
</kendo-dialog>
```

Here is the template of the 'hello-grid' component:

```
<kendo-grid
      [data]="gridView"
      [pageSize]="pageSize"
      [skip]="skip"
      [pageable]="{
        buttonCount: buttonCount,
        info: info,
        type: type,
        pageSizes: pageSizes,
        previousNext: previousNext
      }"
      [scrollable]="'none'"
      (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
    >
</kendo-grid>
```

Runnable plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/RyxR8ts2CRy229RXjXzF?p=preview

The pager works just fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: I corrected my grid code by your example and it works.. thanks